# Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed, installed numpy using pip

Tags: numpy, python-3.5

I try to run a project from GitHUB that demands *python3.5* and *numpy* installed.
I've installed *numpy* with `pip3.5 install numpy` and got the following error:

> raise ImportError(msg) ImportError:
>   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
>   Otherwise reinstall numpy.

The original error was:

> cannot import name multiarray

I've tried to reinstall *numpy* and so I did, but this didn't solve the problem.
The environment is

- ubuntu 16.4,
- python 3.5,
- numpy version installed: 1.15.1

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Maybe knowing the name(link!?) of the project would be helpful.